# Removing Code by using rereplace

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Hi Have the following code, I am using the following code to remove the contents from the page which i do not know:

I am using regex, and i cannot use jsoup, please do not provide any jsoup link or code because that will be useless to use here for me..

```
<cfset removetitle = rereplacenocase(cfhttp.filecontent, '<title[^>]*>(.+)</title>', "\1")>
```

Now above the same way, i want to use the follwoing things:

```
1. <base href="http://search.google.com">
2. <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
3. and there are 5 tables inside the body, i want to remove the 2nd table.,
```

Can anyone guide on this

Comment: Take a look at jSoup - http://jsoup.org/. It is really the best tool for HTML/DOM parsing like this.

Comment: Scott is right. Why isn't jSoup an option? As to a regex solution, does the second table have an id attribute unique in the document? This is possible with regex but there are problems that regex cannot always reliably solve.

Comment: come on guys, i had written in my code [jsoup] is not an option for me, i love jsoup, i had gone through its documentation, its awesome stuff, but i am limited as of now, i am unable to do

Comment: as an update; the first two i had done like this, hopefully it is right way: `REReplaceNoCase(remBase, "<\s*link[^>]*>", "","one")`

Comment: Well, as I asked before, does the second table have a unique html ID?

Comment: how do i remove the 2nd table from the 5 table tags

Comment: no it does not have that

Comment: Why is JSoup not an option? No regex will work as reliably as jsoup.

Comment: my client don not like jsoup,

Comment: If your client is not a programmer, they don't even understand what you're talking about. If your client is a programmer, they should endorse doing things the right, and more importantly: reliable, way.

Comment: Your *client* should not be dictating how you go about solving their issues. Regex is simply not really appropriate for extracting DOM elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scott is right, and [Leigh was right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27285133/3917091) before, when you asked a similar question, jSoup is your best option.

As to a regex solution. This is possible with regex but there are problems that regex cannot always solve. For instance, if the first or second table contains a nested table, this regex would trip. (Note that text is not required between the tables, I'm just demonstrating that things can be between the tables)

(If there is always a nested table, regex can handle it, but if there is sometimes a nested table, in other words: unknown), it gets a lot messier.)

```
<cfsavecontent variable="sampledata">
<body>
<table cellpadding="4"></table>stuff
is <table border="5" cellspacing="7"></table>between
<table border="3"></table>the
<table border="2"></table>tables
<table></table>
</body>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset sampledata = rereplace(sampledata,"(?s)(.*?<table.*?>.*?<\/table>.*?)(<table.*?>.*?<\/table>)(.*)","\1\3","ALL") />
<cfoutput><pre>#htmleditformat(sampledata)#</pre></cfoutput>
```

What this does is

`(?s)` sets . to match newlines as well.
`(.*?<table.*?>.*?<\/table>.*?)` Matches everything before the first table, the first table, and everything between it and the second table and sets it as capture group 1.
`(<table.*?>.*?<\/table>)` Matches the second table and creates capture group 2.
`(.*)` matches everything after the second table and creates capture group 3.

And then the third paramters `\1\3` picks up the first and third capture groups.

If you have control of the source document, you can create html comments like

```
<!-- table1 -->
  <table>...</table>
<!-- /table1 -->
```

And then use that in the regex and end up with a more regex-friendly document.

However, still, Scott said it best, not using the proper tool for the task is:

> That is like telling a carpenter, build me a house, but don't use a hammer.

These tools are created because programmers frequently run into precisely the problem you're having, and so they create a tool, and often freely share it, because it does the job much better.