# get last table using regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to get the last table and all its contents using coldfusion,

Here is the kind of structure it has:

```
<div>
<table><table>
<table></table>
<table></table> -  i need this one and all its contents
<div>
```

how can i do this with regex in coldfusion

here is my try something like this:

```
<cfset data = rereplace(data,"(?s)(.*?<table.*?>.*?<\/table>.*?)(<table.*?>.*?<\/table>)(.*)","\1\3","ALL") />
```

but this does seems to be working

Comment: "not working" is vague.  Be more specific.

Comment: specific is: it does not get the table i want, it just skips and my data variable is empty

Comment: This sounds very familiar... Did you ask this question before?

Comment: nopes, i recently signed up this site, i used to ask questions on easycfm.com

Comment: Check out jSoup - http://jsoup.org/. It is great for parsing HTML.

Comment: Your [code is identical to this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27324259/104223). The answer is the same: use JSoup. It is designed specifically to parse HTML, regular expressions are not.

Comment: i am using this now <cfset session.tables_footer = reMatchNoCase('<table[^>]*>(?:[^<]+|<(?!/table>))+',lnk)> - to all tables in a array and use the last one, i tried arrayMax(session.tables_footer), but i am getting an error of non numeric value found

Comment: Like I said, regular expressions are the *wrong* tool for this job. Not sure why you won't try JSoup. It is quite simple. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was going to do this with regex, I would do something like this..

```
<cfset ArrTables = rematchnocase("<table.*?>.*?</table>",data) />
<cfset lastTable = ArrTables[ArrayLen(ArrTables)] />
```

But, as covered time and time again, parsing an external document based on regex is like building a house on sand. A small change can frequently be the downfall of an application. Programmers frequently need to scrape documents for data, so they create tools designed for the task. Like [jSoup](http://jsoup.org).

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern, w/ `s` option

```
.*(<table>.*?<\/table>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/182)

```
.               # Any character except line break
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  <table>       # "<table>"
  .             # Any character except line break
  *?            # (zero or more)(lazy)
  <             # "<"
  \/            # "/"
  table>            # "table>"
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This pattern will do the work: `<table>.*<\/table>(?=\n*<div>)`.

It is basically search for the table closing tag `</table>` which is followed by optionally `\n` and opening div tag `<div>`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vL9mP1/2

Comment: Only thing I can suggest: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html